# Export object data from CAD to Shp

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, export, feature-class, cad

I am using the tool Feature Class to Feature Class to export polygons from a CAD File.  An example piece of data in CAD looks like this: 
[image: CAD Properties window for a Polygon]

My problem is that I am unable to export any of the object data circled in blue.  The tool works fine, but I cannot get that data out of CAD into a shapefile, although the data under the General and Geometry tabs come out fine.  In the field mappings part of the tool, I cannot get any of those fields as an option for input field, which was my first thought.

I'm not very experienced with CAD and am unsure of the underlying data structure.

ArcGIS Desktop version is 10.3.  Cad is Civil 3D 2014

Comment: Try the import from CAD, it imports into a geodatabase and may be able to find the referenced fields. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000024000000

Comment: What kind of CAD files do you have ?

Comment: @PROBERT they are .dwg files created wholly in CAD Civil 3D 2014.

Comment: Have you tried to bring them (dwg) to ArcMap and then select one of them on the list and right click on the dwg layer and scroll down that says "Convert CAD Feature Layer or Convert CAD Feature Dataset ? I hope this is the only CAD you are working on.. or if you had not use the To Geodatabase's CAD to Geodatabase toolbox ?